# What is the equivalent command for bcdboot in bcdedit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, bcdedit, bcdboot

Making a new boot entry for Windows 7/8 (for dual boot) can apparently be done very easily with `bcdboot`. For example (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/511582/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-dual-boot-windows-installations)):

```
bcdboot D:\windows
```

Now, reading through forums I find people using `bcdedit` for more complex booting, like booting from VHD and such.

So I assume there is an equivalent command(s) in `bcdedit` for `bcdboot D:\windows`, but I am not sure which. Knowing what `bcdboot` does in terms of `bcdedit` would surely help me understand `bcdedit` better.

Comment: They are slightly different tools, and they appear to be independent. Putting it short `bcdboot` tries to repair what already exists, `bcdedit` enables you to directly alter the bootloader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been more than a few years, and even now with Windows 10 the BCDEDIT program remains as mysterious as before. Slightly more than a year ago, I had to learn about BCDEDIT the hard way and I didn't have the faintest idea how BCDEDIT or BCDBOOT was supposed to work. To answer your question, if BCDBOOT can be used to create the template to make a bootable Windows entry in the BCD, then BCDEDIT can probably do the same with a lot more commands and typing, as follows:-

`C:\>bcdedit /create /application OSLOADER
The entry {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} was successfully created.`

If you check inside your BCD to find that particular {ID} which was created, then you will see the following:-

`C:\>bcdedit /enum {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc}
Windows Boot Loader
identifier              {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc}`

You would be right to think that there appears to be a lot of information missing for a proper Windows Boot Loader entry in the BCD. The full entry should look something like the one that was created when you first installed Windows, as follows:-

`C:\>bcdedit /enum {current}
Windows Boot Loader
identifier              {current}
device                  boot
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {d3150567-fac9-11e7-a6a0-d6a823273fc8}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                boot
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {fbe9c9e8-fa42-11e7-a9a1-9cb70d586adc}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Legacy`

So in this case, you are now faced with a lot of typing required, as I would think that at the very minimum, your Windows Boot Loader entry must have "identifier", "device", "path", "description" "osdevice" and "systemroot". Therefore, you will now have to type something like the following:-

`C:\>bcdedit /set {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} device <whichever partition this particular Windows installation is located>
C:\>bcdedit /set {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} path <wherever the WINLOAD.EXE file for this particular Windows installation is located in>
C:\>bcdedit /set {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} description "<give a name here, if you use spaces then the entire phrase must be enclosed in quotes>"
C:\>bcdedit /set {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} osdevice <whichever partition this particular Windows installation is located>
C:\>bcdedit /set {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} systemroot <whichever folder the particular Windows installation is located in>`

Lastly, you will need to modify the {bootmgr} entry to allow a choice of operating systems, by typing the following commands:-

`C:\>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} timeout 5
C:\>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu Yes
C:\>bcdedit /displayorder {43083ab0-6bcd-11e8-a9c7-9cb70d586adc} /addlast`

More information here:-

[Adding Boot Entries | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries)

Comment: Nice answer @Turkey. Have you tested this? i.e. are these `bcdedit` commands sufficient to boot Windows?

Comment: @DavorJosipovic Admittedly, I have not tested whether such a minimalist set of commands is sufficient to boot Windows. However, surely it would be reasonable to expect that if all of the properties in a bootable BCD entry were manually typed into the creation of a new BCD entry from scratch, then that new BCD entry would be bootable as well.

Answer (score 4):

Extending on what I said in comment, both `bcdboot` and `bcdedit` are slightly different tools. They are not used for the same purposes and, as they rely only on the contents stored in the BCD (Boot Configuration Data), they are independent.

[`bcdboot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can be best described as "the bootloader installer guy". It can be used to set up the **bootloader** for **existing** Windows partitions (whether they are to be installed, run from a VHD, or already installed).

This is done by copying some files that exist in the `/Windows` directory to a specific location and updating the Master Boot Record in order for it to point to the bootloader.

[`bcdedit`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731662%28WS.10%29.aspx) is a more complex tool, designed to edit the BCD information. Think of it as "the editor guy". One of the possible reasons why many people in the Internet use it in favor of bcdboot is that most dual or multi-booting systems aren't linear and may have several different scenarios that the generic `bcdboot` doesn't cover.

A good example of this is dual-booting Windows XP and 7. As XP doesn't have BCD files, `bcdboot` wouldn't work on it. It might also not be recognized by the latest systems's bootloaders off the box.

`bcdedit` is a quite hefty tool, so some people made tools in order to edit the BCD data from Windows. One of which is [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), which enables you to see and edit manually the BCD configuration and add effortlessly new partitions. As of now, the free version suits most user's needs quite well.

They also made a [tutorial](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/) about how to recover the BCD-based bootloader from the Windows installation disk, which is one of the reasons why I mention the product. If you read it, there is one method (the Nuclear Holocaust) that can be used with `bcdedit` in order to restore the bootloader. `bcdedit` only writes the correct entries into the bootloader, so that you can actually boot into your systems.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Turkey. I tried to follow along and searched a little bit to get the full info needed and I successfully made a new boot entry.

```
bcdedit /create /application osloader
```

The ID I've got was {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32}
I assumed that I'll use the same entry as my normal Windows entry

This is what worked for me

```
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} device partition=C:
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} path \Windows\system32\winload.efi
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} description "Windows 10 but self-made"
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} osdevice partition=C:
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} systemroot \Windows
bcdedit /set {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} detecthal yes
bcdedit /displayorder {a93a2702-2134-11ed-8dca-60f262a3ce32} /addlast
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1141551)

Answer (score -2):

BCDedit is a powerful program than bcdboot in CMD. You should only use BCDedit when in near emergency when your windows1 isn't starting after installing another windows2(vice versa) as it can do a lot more to your computer boot system than the BCDboot command. Although if you're installing windows 8 with any windows(in any order, but preferably install windows 8 first then other windows you want is better), if your wwindows 8 is set the default OS to boot untill you make a selection than windows 8 gives a menu to boot another windows(can be more than 1) present in your HDD. So you will not get any problems Dualbooting your PC with two windows.