# How to access Windows 8 on another hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, boot

I have two hard drives on this computer. I used to dual boot Windows 8 and Windows 7, each separated by physical drive. Windows 8 was my primary OS. I recently re-installed Windows 7 (overriding the existing Windows 7 installation) and lost the OS choice prompt.

How do I boot to Windows 8? How can I edit the boot record and tell the machine to look for another OS or give me the option to choose when I start the computer?

Comment: Do you have windows 8 installation media, have you tried to repair instalation?

Comment: I do have the installation media and I have not tried to repair installation. I should be able to boot into Windows 8 using it? PS. Now I want Windows 7 to be my primary OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was already a similar question here [How to use BCDEdit to dual boot Windows installations?](https://superuser.com/questions/511582/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-dual-boot-windows-installations) , but your case is on reverse-direction.

Assuming that you're currently on windows 7 on drive C:, and windows 8 is on drive F:, then you can run both of these commands from cmd (as administrator):

1. **bcdboot f:\windows** (this maps to Windows 8)
2. **bcdboot c:\windows** (this re-maps to Windows 7)

Comment: Well, that was easy! I just didn't know which keywords to search by. Thank you!