# Two Windows 10 installations, only one recognized in boot files

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

In a computer there were two separate Windows 10 installations on two different Hard Disks. But the boot files were in  Hard Disk 1.

Now Hard Disk 1 is formatted completely and the Windows 10 on it is reinstalled. But this new installation could not recognize the Windows installation on Hard Disk 2. How can I revive the Windows Installation on Hard Disk 2? Is there any boot manager to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not listed in the BCD file as the old one was deleted and the new one only contains the new installation.

I use a tool called [Visual BCD](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/visual_bcd_editor.html) to edit my BCD files.

Take a look at here at a tutorial and some more information:

[How to use BCDEdit to dual boot Windows installations?](https://superuser.com/questions/511582/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-dual-boot-windows-installations)

[How to add a new OS entry via BCDEDIT?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e5f36d6-f0b7-49e6-959d-0b8bad46d7c0/how-to-add-new-os-entry-via-bcdedit-?forum=w7itproinstall)

Comment: Visual BCD fails. Also it seems it is designed for Win 7 -.

Comment: Oh right, did not know. I have used it on 8.1 successfully. Windows actually has it built in, it is just that it is command line and a bit trickier to use.