# Only one OS boots from partitioned dual boot HDD

Tags: boot

I have partitioned my HDD and installed /cloned Windows 10 Home OS  on both, the idea being that if one OS fails I can switch to the other identical one.  Both OS show on the  dual boot prompt, but unfortunately only one OS boots.  I tried just about everything.How can I get them both booting, either one or the other?

It is odd, because on the same partition of the same HDD I used to have Windows 7 along with Windows 10 and I could boot on both if I wanted. I removed Windows7.

Comment: Are you using the same OEM license for both systems?  It may be that one did not activate because of this

Answer (score 0):

Boot to WinRE and use [**`BootRec`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options):

1. **Boot to WinRE:**

   1. Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced Startup - Restart Now
   2. Troubleshooting > Advanced > Boot to Command Prompt
2. **Issue the following:**

   - **BIOS:** `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd`
   - **UEFI:** `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd`
3. **Reboot**

   - Close terminal > Continue to Windows 10

Comment: Thanks

I have already done all of the above , unsuccessfully. I had downloaded tHe Windows 10 installation image from Windows for free by changing some of the parameters on their WEB  page, following the instructions of a WEB site I found.The OS was subsequently activated. 
I think the problem may be that I cloned the 2nd OS from the other partition, instead of fresh installing it. 
Anyway, one working OS is enough, because I have already made a system BUP with Acronis, in case the current OS becomes unbootable or the HDD fails.

Thanks for ypur help anyway

Ittiandro

Comment: @IttiandroVivona If `BootRec /RebuildBCD` isn't adding the other OS (I'm assuming Windows 7), and Windows 7's boot files still exist on the boot partition, then you'll need to manually add Windows 7 to the newer BCD store via `BCDedit`, which can be done while booted to Windows (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/511582/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-dual-boot-windows-installations) question & answer)