# Windows Boot manager showing blank > then normal boot after the 30 secs

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, dualboot, bug

I installed second Windows 10 on my laptop (now it's dual boot with two Windows 10 installations). The newer installation is set as default and first in the Windows Boot Manager menu. But when I restart the laptop, it doesn't show the Windows Boot Manager for 30 secs (the time you have to select the OS before it selects the first listed one), and instead it shows a black screen (with display backlight turned on) for 30 secs and then boots into the default OS. I tried pressing enter during the black screen phase and it boots right away to the default OS, so obviously the menu is technically there but the GUI is not shown.

Any ideas?

This might be related to the hibernate/fast boot option in Windows 10, since the 30 sec black screen appears only when I restart my laptop, and not when I turn it off completely and turn it on afterwards (in this case it shows normal Windows Boot Manager for 30 secs).
I'm thinking of turning the timer off and try booting into the default OS right away without Windows Boot Manager menu, but I'm afraid it would complicate things further. Anyhow, I think I don't need the older installation at this point and I think I'll completely delete it

Comment: You shouldn't be using fast boot in dual-boot.

Comment: How do I turn it off? By running "powercfg -h off" on both OS?
Also, is the fast boot bugging it so its shows black screen for 30 secs?
I'm afraid to change anything at this point.
Btw, at the end, I'd like to delete the older installation and keep the new one only. So I'd first disable the timer in msconfig so it'd boot into the default immediately, skipping the Windows Boot Manager meanwhile. But I'm afraid it might result in an unbootable laptop.

Comment: I added an answer about disabling fast boot.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using fast boot in dual-boot.

To disable (in both Windows versions):

- Run Power Options
- Click *Choose what the power buttons do*
- Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable*
- Click "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" so that the check-mark disappears
- Click *Save changes*.

Comment: But if I disable on one OS, then reboot to disable on the other OS, would the other OS boot for certain or could any problems appear?

Comment: This needs to be done in both instances.

Comment: I tried, there's still an issue.
Now even when I shut it down and turn it on (instead of restarting) there's black screen for 30 secs and the boot into default OS.
Seems there're like two Windows Boot Managers, and the newer one is set on boot. And the newer one is bugged.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the computer BIOS or EFI?

Comment: Not sure how I can check that. I think it's BIOS. It's ASUS X509JA.

Comment: Looks like BIOS. In any case, you wouldn't have had this problem with EFI. See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/511582/how-to-use-bcdedit-to-dual-boot-windows-installations/1278406) and especially the [answer by Motorcycleboy](https://superuser.com/a/562202/8672).

Comment: Can you please add me on discord - username: manvas555

Comment: Btw I don't have an issue with boot options, I have issue with Windows Boot Managers.

Comment: I don't use discord.